# Azure get-credentials errors running in golang program

Tags: python, linux, azure, go

I am trying to azure acs kubernetes credentials with the following script:

```
#! /bin/sh
az login --service-principal --username=user -password=password --tenant=tenant
az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=rg --name=acs1 --file=/tmp/kubeconfig.json --ssh-key-file=private.key --output=json --debug --verbose
```

Running the script from command line on the mac works ok.  When I try to run a golang program "cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", scriptName)" that calls the same script on the same computer I get the following error:

```
No existing session
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aarontorgerson/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/main.py", line 36, in main
    cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args)
  File "/Users/aarontorgerson/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/application.py", line 211, in execute
    result = expanded_arg.func(params)
  File "/Users/aarontorgerson/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 351, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aarontorgerson/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 555, in _execute_command
    reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/aarontorgerson/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 532, in _execute_command
    result = op(client, **kwargs) if client else op(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/aarontorgerson/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 785, in k8s_get_credentials
    _k8s_get_credentials_internal(name, acs_info, path, ssh_key_file)
  File "/Users/aarontorgerson/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 806, in _k8s_get_credentials_internal
    '.kube/config', path_candidate, key_filename=ssh_key_file)
  File "/Users/aarontorgerson/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/acs_client.py", line 62, in secure_copy
    ssh.connect(host, username=user, pkey=pkey)
  File "/Users/aarontorgerson/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 394, in connect
    look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)
  File "/Users/aarontorgerson/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 649, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
SSHException: No existing session
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please format your exception traceback with a coding style wrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description and the error information `SSHException: No existing session`, it sounds like you were using `os/exec` for calling your shell script file,  but failed because command `az` needs to use something like `azureProfile.json` at the path `.azure` within a ssh session.

So I suggested you can try to use the code below with `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` package to do it.

Here is my sample code for Linux which I think the same as on MacOS.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func getHostKey(host string) (ssh.PublicKey, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(filepath.Join(os.Getenv("HOME"), ".ssh", "known_hosts"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    var hostKey ssh.PublicKey
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fields := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), " ")
        if len(fields) != 3 {
            continue
        }
        if strings.Contains(fields[0], host) {
            var err error
            hostKey, _, _, _, err = ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(scanner.Bytes())
            if err != nil {
                return nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("error parsing %q: %v", fields[2], err))
            }
            break
        }
    }

    if hostKey == nil {
        return nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("no hostkey for %s", host))
    }
    return hostKey, nil
}

func main() {
    hostKey, err := getHostKey("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "peter",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password("peter ssh password"),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.FixedHostKey(hostKey),
    }
    // Dial your ssh server.
    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "localhost:22", config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("unable to connect: ", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    session, err := conn.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to create session: ", err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // Once a Session is created, you can execute a single command on
    // the remote side using the Run method.
    var b bytes.Buffer
    session.Stdout = &b
    if err := session.Run("./test.sh"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to run: " + err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(b.String())
}
```

**Notes**: There must be a record like the content below for `localhost` in your `.ssh/known_hosts` file. If not, you can first login via ssh to generate it and change the host with `localhost`.

> |localhost|qx8q1geNHGyRFp8Ttu+m2xY4OpU=|noyfrjpDRvtIzP2gzWEV77VZULo= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBKXlyt/EFLnqwlNDimn73+wZVgCh3dhXi2YMWN6tHUj5LMirrUt0AtmQQVHex2b2ur79L5P6/L2J28NID569qAA=

Hope it helps.